# Javascript: Set cookie - Dynamic URL parameter Name

Tags: javascript, url, cookies, dynamic, parameter-passing

I've been strugling looking for a way to set a cookie if a URL parameter is persent. The problem is, the name of the URL parameter is half dynamic.

The URL would be:

```
http://zzzz.test.bbbb/index.html?transaction[XXXX]=YYYYY
```

The XXXX is the userID that will change depending on the customer and YYYY is the actual value (transaction number).

I have the following code but it won't recognize the brakets nor what is inside. How can I set it to recognize the URL parameter including the brakets and the dynamic userID within the brakets?

Here is my code:

```
function URLparam(name) {
    return unescape(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}

if (URLparam("transaction") !== null && !get_cookie ("Transacion_ID")) {
    set_cookie ("Transacion_ID", URLparam("transaction"));
}

if (get_cookie ("Transacion_ID")) {
    console.log(get_cookie ("transaction"));
}
});
```

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

NEW ADDITION ==========================

For a link with the following format:

```
http://zzzz.test.bbbb/index.html?transaction[XXXX][zzzzz]=YYYYY
```

How would the correct `getParameterByName` function look like in order to recognize the URL parameter `transaction[XXXX][zzzzz]` ?

I've tried this but it does not work:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
var regex = new RegExp(name + '(?:\\[\\d+\\]?:\\[\\d+\\])?=' + '(.+?)(&|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The cookie you're setting is `Transacion_ID`, why are you logging `transaction`?

Comment: You're looking for a URL parameter named `transaction`, not `transaction[XXXX]`. There's nothing in your `URLparam()` function that allows optional brackets after the `name`.

Comment: The name of the cookie can be changed. The main problem is how to look for the URL parameter `transaction[XXXX]` where XXX is any numeric value and the brackets are also recognized

Comment: @Barmar: what would you add to `URLparam()` for it to allow and recognize the brackets and the value within?

Comment: @Barmar I'm having the same problem with a link that includes two values in square brackets within the URL parameter name. I have updated the question showing the code I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of `URLparam()` allows an optional `[XXX]` after the name:

```
function URLparam(name) {
    return unescape(
        (RegExp(name + '(?:\\[\\d+\\])?=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

To allow multiple array indexes, change `?` (for optional) to `*` (for any number of repetitions):

```
function URLparam(name) {
    return unescape(
        (RegExp(name + '(?:\\[\\d+\\])*=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a link that includes two values in square brackets within the URL parameter name. I have updated the question showing the code I'm using